# Plot single error bar for multiple lines in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to plot a line graph. I will like to add single error bar for names A and B for each week.

This is the code I tried to used to create the line graph

```
et1<- data.frame (names=c("A", "A","A","B", "B","B"), 
                  weeks=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), 
                  dat=c(19,20,17, 24,9,8))


et1 %>% ggplot(aes(weeks, dat, colour = names)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

This is the sample I am trying to create[sample of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF49r.jpg)

I produced this using excel with lsd values

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample data and be sure to indicate what values in your sample data are for the error bar.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have error bars, you either need multiple points at each week for each group, or upper and lower limits pre-calculated. Since you have not included any data, it is not clear what your set-up is here. Assuming you have multiple points for each group A and B each week, you could do:

```r
et1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(weeks, dat, colour = names)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1)
```

[image]

If this is not the case, we really need more information about how you intend to generate error bars.

---

**Made-up data used for example**

```r
set.seed(1)

et1 <- data.frame(weeks = rep(1:5, each = 10),
                  names = rep(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5), 5),
                  dat = rnorm(50, rep(rep(c(10, 15), each = 5), 5)))
```

Comment: The graph should have only one error bar for each week. Just like the sample in my question.

Comment: @OlanrewajuOlogunde but where is the information coming from to create these error bars? What do they mean? If you only have 1 point at each week per group how can you work out an error?

Answer (score 0):

Be reminded to include the "Hmisc" and "Tidyverse"

Comment: The core of this question is on error bars, not the the packages needed. Although you are correct, you are not addressing the primary concern.